# sudo tasksel install ubuntu-desktop doesn't work

Tags: sudo

After I type this command and the password
nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you just do `sudo tasksel`? Can you use the TUI to install it?

Comment: And if you want Ubuntu Desktop why didn't you install the desktop version instead?

Comment: try
$ sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop

Answer (score 2):

if you want to install a task use a `^`behind it ...

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^
```

That method replaced the tasksel command. First and last few lines:

```
$ sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'kerneloops' for task 'ubuntu-desktop'
Note, selecting 'openvpn' for task 'ubuntu-desktop'
Note, selecting 'fontconfig' for task 'ubuntu-desktop'
Note, selecting 'libvulkan1' for task 'ubuntu-desktop'
Note, selecting 'gkbd-capplet' for task 'ubuntu-desktop'

....
systemd systemd-sysv systemd-timesyncd
32 upgraded, 132 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
Need to get 79,6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 268 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

-see the `task` at line 4

Without the `^` it does not use the "task" install ...

```
$ sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
```

Comment: come on, they should just warning about the tasksel deprecation and give me that command line.

Comment: they have; you just missed it ;-)

Comment: really? from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel, it looks like the `^` method is the old alternative. the tasksel is the new thing after that. And I search tasksel deprecate. nothing comes up